# How to implement this bottom navigation bar

Tags: java, android, navigationbar

Hei I have the new android studio 4.1

I have imported a bottom navigation menu from git hub [here this one](https://github.com/ibrahimsn98/SmoothBottomBar)

Now I have set up dependencies correctly
I did all the things necessary but still, there are no actions in the navigation bar, the colour is not changing. even the menus are not displaying

here is the main activity code

```
     <me.ibrahimsn.lib.SmoothBottomBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/menu" />
    
    
          </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> 



this is the menu code
  

       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     
            <item android:id="@+id/home"
            android:title="Home"/>
    
            <item android:id="@+id/rank"
            android:title="Rank"/>
            </menu>
```

now still the background is white see this:  image still not changing
[image]

Comment: Being that this is a 3rd party library, it's not going to be easy to answer. But there are a couple of things you can check. I notice right away that you have no icon for the menu items. Can you add an icon to each menu item to see if that works? Also, try changing the background. The text might be white so it would appear to have no items.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this line in your layout parent tag:

```
xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```